# Ensure belongs_to combination is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know what is the proper manner to ensure that there is only one record with the same couple of foreign keys. Let's assume a class named LineItem, which belongs to an `cart` and to `item`. Something like:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :item
```

The point is: I want to make unique the combination of this two "attributes". At this time, my approach was using a `after_save` callback but I realized thats pretty poor. How do you resolve this? I was thinking in a PORO class (something like LineItemSaver) but I'm not completely convinced.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do a uniqueness validation?

```
validates :cart_id, uniqueness: {scope: :item_id}
```

Comment: I didn't know I can do that with `uniqueness`! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If I understood your question correctly,you want the `scope` option of the `validates_uniqueness_of`. If so, this should work.

In your `LineItem` model:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :item 
  validates_uniqueness_of :cart_id, scope: :item_id

end
```

And also, you should be generating a migration to add this:

```
add_index :line_items, [ :cart_id, :item_id ], :unique => true
```

More Info **[here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)**.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a validate method to ensure that item_id is unique scoped to :cart_id

Something like:

```
validates :item_id, uniqueness: { scope: :cart_id }
```

Or if you want to fix the situation and simply increment the quantity you could also:

```
validate :ensure_line_item_uniqueness

def ensure_line_item_uniqueness
  ... whatever fixes the situation here ...
end
```